# reshape is deprecated issue when I pick series from pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

When I try to take one series from dataframe I get this issue

> anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:52: FutureWarning: reshape is deprecated and will raise in a subsequent release. Please use .values.reshape(...) instead
>     return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)

This is the code snippet

```
for idx, categories in enumerate(categorical_columns):
    ax = plt.subplot(3,3,idx+1)
    ax.set_xlabel(categories[0])
    box = [df[df[categories[0]] == atype].price for atype in categories[1]] 
    ax.boxplot(box)
```

Comment: How working `box = [df.loc[df[categories[0]] == atype, 'price' ] for atype in categories[1]]` ?

Comment: Or is necessary upgrade pandas/numpy/matplotlib.

Comment: still, the issue is there @jezrael

Comment: Do you try upgrade?

Comment: @jezrael It worked fine after I upgraded it, take this upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For avoid chained indexing use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
box = [df.loc[df[categories[0]] == atype, 'price'] for atype in categories[1]]
```

And for remove `FutureWarning` is necessary upgrade `pandas` with `matplotlib`.